# Having trouble grouping columns in Linq query with multiple joins

Tags: linq, model-view-controller, group-by, controller, viewmodel

I have an MVC ViewModel that I'd like to pass through to a Razor view. In the controller, I've created a database context and joined tables together using Linq. Once summed and grouped, I'm getting an error:

> Error  CS1061  'decimal' does not contain a definition for 'GroupBy' and no accessible extension method 'GroupBy' accepting a first argument of type 'decimal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

I've gone through almost every example on stack overflow and google and couldn't find an example that matched the structure of my query. Also, the MS examples are very trivial and are not of much use.

Here is the action in the controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetEmployeeReleasedAllocatedBonus(int eid)
    {
        var employeeReleasedAllocatedBonus =
            (from br in _context.BonusReleases
                join emp in _context.Employees
                    on new
                    {
                        br.EmployeeID,
                        empID = br.EmployeeID
                    } equals new
                    {
                        emp.EmployeeID,
                        empID = eid
                    }
                join job in _context.Jobs on br.JobID equals job.JobID
                join bonus in _context.Bonus
                    on new
                    {
                        br.JobID,
                        empID = br.EmployeeID
                    }
                    equals new
                    {
                        bonus.JobID,
                        empID = bonus.EmployeeID
                    }
                select new EmployeeAllocatedReleasedBonusViewModel()
                {
                    AllocatedToEmployee = br.Amount, AllocatedPercentage = bonus.Amount * 100
                    ,
                    JobNumber = job.JobNumber, JobDescription = job.JobDescription

                })
            .ToList()
            .Sum(s => s.AllocatedToEmployee)
            .GroupBy(g => new {g.JobNumber, g.JobDescription, g.AllocatedPercentage});

        return Ok(employeeReleasedAllocatedBonus);
    }
```

It's worth mentioning that the AllocatedPercentage datatype is a decimal. However, I've tried changing it to string but the error message stays.

Also tried using the group functionality right before .ToList() but that didn't work either.

Comment: I am wondering if the `bonus.Amount * 100` is causing the problem. Your `select new` should look like this: `select new { br, bonus, job }` than after the `ToList()` return the field and do the calculations.

Comment: `.Sum(s => s.AllocatedToEmployee)` will return a decimal value, How can you group it again.

Comment: Harisyam, I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that you are trying to help, but your comment wasn't very constructive.

Comment: Hi Flavio, I removed the *100 but the error persists. From what I gather the problem is that I'm passing the result of the SUM (i.e. a decimal) to the GroupBy - which doesn't contain a method for GroupBy.

Answer (score 0):

After `ToList()` you have a `List<EmployeeAllocatedReleasedBonusViewModel>`.

In `Sum(s => s.AllocatedToEmployee)`, every `s` is one `EmployeeAllocatedReleasedBonusViewModel`. Apparently a `EmployeeAllocatedReleasedBonusViewModel` has a property `AllocatedToEmployee` which is probably of type decimal. This can be summed into one decimal.

The result of the `Sum` (a decimal) is the input of your `GroupBy`. Does type decimal have a method `GroupBy`? Of course it doesn't!

Alas you forgot to tell us your requirements. It is difficult to extract them from code that doesn't do what you want.

It seems to me that you have two one-to-many relations:

- `Employees` have zero or more `BonusReleases`. Every `BonusRelease` belongs to exactly one `Employee` using foreign key
- `Jobs` have zero or more `BonusReleases`. Every `BonusRelease` belongs to exactly one `Job`.

Now what do you want: do you want all `JobNumbers` and `JobDescriptions` of all `Jobs` with the total of their `AllocatedPercentage`? I'm not sure what the `Employees` do within this query.

> Whenever you want items with their sub-items, like Schools with their Students, Customers with their Orders, Orders with their OrderLines, use GroupJoin. If you want it the other way round: Student with the School that he attends, Order with the Customer who placed the Order, use Join.

```
var result = dbContext.Jobs.GroupJoin(dbContext.BonusReleases,
    job => job.Id,                       // from every Job take the primary key
    bonusRelease => bonusReleas.JobId,   // from every BonusRelease take the foreign key

    // parameter ResultSelector: take every Job with all its BonusReleases to make a new:
    (job, bonusReleasesOfThisJob) => new
    {
        JobNumber = job.JobNumber,
        JobDescription = job.JobDescription

        // do you want the total of all allocated percentages?
        TotalAllocatedPercentages = bonusReleasesOfThisJob
            .Select(bonus => bonus.Amount)
            .Sum(),
            // do something to make it a percentage

         // or do you want a sequence of allocated percentages?
         TotalAllocatedPercentages = bonusReleasesOfThisJob
            .Select(bonus => bonus.Amount)
            .ToList(),
});
```

Or do you want the JobNumber / JobDescription / Total allocated bonus per Employee?

```
var result = dbContext.Employees.GroupJoin(dbContext.BonusReleases,
    employee => employee.Id,    // from every Employee take the primary key
    bonus => bonus.EmployeeId,  // from every BonusRelease take the foreign key

    (employee, bonusesOfThisEmployee) => new
    {
        // Employee properties:
        EmployeeId =  employee.Id,
        EmpoyeeName = employee.Name,

        // for the jobs: Join the bonusesOfThisEmployee with the Jobs:
        Jobs = dbContext.Jobs.GroupJoin(bonusOfThisEmployee,
            job => job.Id,
            bonusOfThisEmployee => bonusOfThisEmployee.JobId,

            (job, bonusesOfThisJob) => new
            {
                Number = job.Id,
                Description = job.Description,
                TotalBonus = bonusOfThisJob.Select(bonus => bonus.Amount).Sum(),
            }),
   });
```

Comment: Hi Harald. Thanks for your help. I've uploaded the ER diagram here https://pasteboard.co/IiVK7IO.png

The Allocated Percentage is fixed per employee per job. An employee can receive multiple bonus releases for every job. Say if the job went on for 3 years, the employee could receive a payout in 2016,2017,2018 etc. I only want to see the total amount released - per employee per job.

Therefore the following are the Group By fields: Job Number, Job Description, EmployeeFullName, Allocated Percentage.

The field to sum on: AllocatedToEmployee.

To your question, it would be the latter.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I'll read up on Group Join. As per your explanation it makes sense to use it in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Harald's comment was key - after ToList(), I had a list of . Therefore I took a step back and said what if I put the results into an anonymous object first. Then do the group by and then the sum, putting the final result into the view model. It worked. Here is the answer.

```
var employeeReleasedAllocatedBonus =
            (from br in _context.BonusReleases
                join emp in _context.Employees
                    on new
                    {
                        br.EmployeeID,
                        empID = br.EmployeeID
                    } equals new
                    {
                        emp.EmployeeID,
                        empID = eid
                    }
                join job in _context.Jobs on br.JobID equals job.JobID
                join bonus in _context.Bonus
                    on new
                    {
                        br.JobID,
                        empID = br.EmployeeID
                    }
                    equals new
                    {
                        bonus.JobID,
                        empID = bonus.EmployeeID
                    }
                select new 
                {
                    AllocatedToEmployee = br.Amount
                    ,AllocatedPercentage = bonus.Amount * 100
                    ,JobNumber = job.JobNumber
                    ,JobDescription = job.JobDescription
                })
                .GroupBy(g => new {g.JobNumber, g.JobDescription, g.AllocatedPercentage})
                .Select(t => new EmployeeAllocatedReleasedBonusViewModel
                {
                JobNumber = t.Key.JobNumber,
                JobDescription = t.Key.JobDescription,
                AllocatedPercentage = t.Key.AllocatedPercentage,
                AllocatedToEmployee = t.Sum(ae => ae.AllocatedToEmployee)
                });
```